# Applying settings in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have:

```
var cp = Ext.create('Extensible.calendar.CalendarPanel', {
    id: 'calendar-remote',
    eventStore: eventStore,
    calendarStore: calendarStore
});
```

And I want to apply an option to it:

```
readOnly: true
```

from an external function. I've used

```
Ext.apply(cp, {
      readOnly: true
});
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply all config settings before component is created. After that you can call setReadOnly() method (assuming your component inherits from `Ext.form.field.Base`)

Comment: Does Extensible have "setReadOnly()" ?

Comment: I don't know. It doesn't come with ExtJS, does it?

Comment: Ajax requests take time so I cannot apply them before component is created.

Comment: Well, it seems you can't set readonly to these components after they're created. If you look into `http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/CalendarView.html#cfg-Ext.ensible.cal.CalendarView-readOnly` you'll see that a lot of listeners are attached during view creation basing on config `readOnly` setting. And no, there is no `setReadOnly()` method available. I guess you should ask this question on their support forum: http://ext.ensible.com/forum/

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('EIM.view.calendar.Panel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.calendar_panel',
    ...
    initComponent: function() {
        this.readOnly = (1 === 1);//or anything else
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype : 'extensible.calendarpanel',
                readOnly: this.readOnly,
                eventStore: this.eventStore,
                ...
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

It should be work...